# Execute Activity only for first time

Tags: android, python

I am using android-python27 project in order to execute python scripts via my apk and I want to merge my own already finished application with it.
First of all there is this activity in android-python project:

```
    package com.android.python27;

import com.android.python27.config.GlobalConstants;
import com.android.python27.support.Utils;
import com.googlecode.android_scripting.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.util.Log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScriptActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog myProgressDialog; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // mounted sdcard ?
        //if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals("mounted")) {
        //  Log.e(GlobalConstants.LOG_TAG, "External storage is not mounted");
        //  
        //  Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "External storage not mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //  toast.show();
        //  return;
        //}

        // install needed ?
        boolean installNeeded = isInstallNeeded();

        if(installNeeded) {
          setContentView(R.layout.install); 
          new InstallAsyncTask().execute();
        }
        else {
            runScriptService();
            finish();
        }

        //onStart();
  }

    private void sendmsg(String key, String value) {
          Message message = installerHandler.obtainMessage();
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putString(key, value);
          message.setData(bundle);
          installerHandler.sendMessage(message);
       }

       final Handler installerHandler = new Handler() {
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                Bundle bundle = message.getData();

                if (bundle.containsKey("showProgressDialog")) {
                   myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ScriptActivity.this, "Installing", "Loading", true); 
                }
                else if (bundle.containsKey("setMessageProgressDialog")) {
                    if (myProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        myProgressDialog.setMessage(bundle.getString("setMessageProgressDialog"));
                    }
                }
                else if (bundle.containsKey("dismissProgressDialog")) {
                    if (myProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                else if (bundle.containsKey("installSucceed")) {
                  Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Install Succeed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                  toast.show();
                }
                else if (bundle.containsKey("installFailed")) {
                      Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Install Failed. Please check logs.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                      toast.show();
                }
           }
       };

      public class InstallAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
           }

           @Override
           protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {       
            Log.i(GlobalConstants.LOG_TAG, "Installing...");

            // show progress dialog
            sendmsg("showProgressDialog", "");

            sendmsg("setMessageProgressDialog", "Please wait...");
            createOurExternalStorageRootDir();

            // Copy all resources
            copyResourcesToLocal();

            // TODO
            return true;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Boolean installStatus) {
            sendmsg("dismissProgressDialog", "");

            if(installStatus) {
                sendmsg("installSucceed", "");
            }
            else {
                sendmsg("installFailed", "");
            }

            runScriptService();
            finish();
           }

      }

  private void runScriptService() {
      if(GlobalConstants.IS_FOREGROUND_SERVICE) {
          startService(new Intent(this, ScriptService.class));
      }
      else {
          startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundScriptService.class)); 
      }
  }

    private void createOurExternalStorageRootDir() {
        Utils.createDirectoryOnExternalStorage( this.getPackageName() );
    }

    // quick and dirty: only test a file
    private boolean isInstallNeeded() {
        File testedFile = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + GlobalConstants.PYTHON_MAIN_SCRIPT_NAME);
        if(!testedFile.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


     private void copyResourcesToLocal() {
            String name, sFileName;
            InputStream content;

            R.raw a = new R.raw();
            java.lang.reflect.Field[] t = R.raw.class.getFields();
            Resources resources = getResources();

            boolean succeed = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                try {
                    name = resources.getText(t[i].getInt(a)).toString();
                    sFileName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, name.length());
                    content = getResources().openRawResource(t[i].getInt(a));
                    content.reset();

                    // python project
                    if(sFileName.endsWith(GlobalConstants.PYTHON_PROJECT_ZIP_NAME)) {
                        succeed &= Utils.unzip(content, this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/", true);
                    }
                    // python -> /data/data/com.android.python27/files/python
                    else if (sFileName.endsWith(GlobalConstants.PYTHON_ZIP_NAME)) {
                        succeed &= Utils.unzip(content, this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/", true);
                        FileUtils.chmod(new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/python/bin/python" ), 0755);
                    }
                    // python extras -> /sdcard/com.android.python27/extras/python
                    else if (sFileName.endsWith(GlobalConstants.PYTHON_EXTRAS_ZIP_NAME)) {
                        Utils.createDirectoryOnExternalStorage( this.getPackageName() + "/" + "extras");
                        Utils.createDirectoryOnExternalStorage( this.getPackageName() + "/" + "extras" + "/" + "tmp");
                        succeed &= Utils.unzip(content, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + this.getPackageName() + "/extras/", true);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(GlobalConstants.LOG_TAG, "Failed to copyResourcesToLocal", e);
                    succeed = false;
                }
            } // end for all files in res/raw

     }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      String s = "System infos:";
      s += " OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
      s += " | OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
      s += " | Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
      s += " | Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";

      Log.i(GlobalConstants.LOG_TAG, s);

      //finish();
  }

}
```

And here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest   package="com.android.python27"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0"
            android:installLocation="internalOnly"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-sdk     android:minSdkVersion="4"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <application  android:debuggable="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name="com.android.python27.ScriptApplication">

    <activity   android:name=".ScriptActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">

      <intent-filter>
        <action     android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category   android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

       <intent-filter>
        <action     android:name="com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.ACTION_LAUNCH_FOR_RESULT" />
        <category   android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service    android:name="ScriptService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.python27.ScriptService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service    android:name="BackgroundScriptService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.python27.BackgroundScriptService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".RpcServerService" />

    <activity   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:name="com.googlecode.android_scripting.activity.FutureActivity" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

    <activity   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
                android:name="com.android.python27.DialogActivity"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".RpcServerLauncher"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

  <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> -->
<!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/> -->
<!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> -->
<!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> -->
<!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/> -->

  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/> -->         


  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />  -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BACKUP"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BACKUP_DATA"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BRICK"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.DUMP"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH_CONTROL"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.PERFORM_CDMA_PROVISIONING"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/> -->
  <!-- <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/> -->


<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission> -->
</manifest>
```

When you first execute the starting android-python27 application appears an activity which installs the required folders in my device. Whenever you try it open it again it does nothing (it doesn't open an activity, only execute a python scripts which prints "hello").
What I want is to change the manifest file in order to open my own activity after I open again the application.(The activity which installs the required folders locally should be executed only the first time).

Any advice would be helpful and deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main activity in `manifests.xml` can't be changed,that means the first activity created can't be changed once decided,but the view of first activity can show nothing and execute your custom logic and go to another activity.

To satisfy your demand,you can start an activity when detected your file has been installed.

```
if(installNeeded) {
      setContentView(R.layout.install); 
      new InstallAsyncTask().execute();
    }
    else {
        runScriptService();
        finish();
        startActivity(this,<nextactivity you want to goto>) //add this
    }
```